# Laravel (vlucas/phpdotenv) changing env values dynamically

Tags: laravel, lumen, phpdotenv

In my test cases, I try to change some of the environment variables to create better test case coverage.

Laravel by default, only support get environment variable by `env($key, $default = null)`, I cannot change the variable.

The `Illuminate\Support\Env` only supports `get`, does not support `set`.

Also, by default Laravel uses `vlucas/phpdotenv` to managing the environment variable. Most of them are using `ImmutableWriter`.

Is there any easy way to support dynamically changing environment variables are stored in `ImmutableWriter`.

Again, the solution is no necessary to (and should not) be implemented in production for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 7+ Closure has some interesting features, which can bypass private/protected checks.
It is very hacky, however, pretty good for test cases written.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Env;

function resetEnvValue($name, $value)
{
    $environmentRepository = Env::getRepository();

    $fn = function () use ($name, $value) {
        $fn = function() use ($name, $value) {
            $this->writer->write($name, $value);
        };
        $fn->call($this->writer);
    };
    $fn->call($environmentRepository);
}

resetEnvValue('TIMER', 1);

var_dump(env('TIMER')); // int(1)

resetEnvValue('TIMER', 2);

var_dump(env('TIMER')); // int(2)
```

Please do not use it production environment, the above code is only suitable for testing since it bypasses all the `ImmutableWriter` protection.